# Getting table-specific costs via SQL query

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a query I can run to determine how much queries against each table are costing us? For instance, the result of this query would at least include something like:

dataset.table1 236TB processed dataset.table2 56GB processed dataset.table3 24kB processed etc

Also is there a way to know what specific queries are costing us the most?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Let's talk first about data and respective data-points to do such a query!
```

Take a look at [`Job Resources`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#resource)
Here you have few useful properties

[`configuration.query.query`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.query) - BigQuery SQL query to execute.
[`statistics.query.referencedTables`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#statistics.query.referencedTables) - Referenced tables for the job.
[`statistics.query.totalBytesBilled`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#statistics.query.totalBytesBilled) - Total bytes billed for the job.
[`statistics.query.totalBytesProcessed`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#statistics.query.totalBytesProcessed) - Total bytes processed for the job.
[`statistics.query.billingTier`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#statistics.query.billingTier) - Billing tier for the job.

Having above data-points would allow you to write relativelly simple query to answer your cost per query and cost per table questions!

```
So, now  - how to get this data available?
```

You can collect your jobs using [`Job.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) API and than loop thru all available jobs and retrieve respective stats via [`Job.get`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get) API - of course dumping retrieved data into BigQuery table. Than you can enjoy analysis!

Or you can use BigQuery's audit logs to track access and cost details (as described in the [`docs`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs)) and export them back to BigQuery for analysis.

The former option (Jobs.list and than Job.get in loop)) gives you ability to get your jobs info even if you don't have audit logs enabled yet, because Job.get API returns information about a specific job that is available for a six month period after creation - so plenty of data for analysis!

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding currently, it is not possible to get processed bytes per table.
In my understanding it would be a great feature through which you can identify and optimize costs and also have a better possibility to understand effectivity of partioning and clustering changes. Currently is just possible to get the totalprocessed bytes for a query and also see which tables were referenced. But there are no easy query and no query at all which makes possible to analyze this cost on the table level which is more granuar then query level.